# zsh: command not found: jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, zsh

I've installed jasmine globally using 'npm install -g jasmine' and it appears to successfully install, but when I then enter 'jasmine -v' it returns 'zsh: command not found: jasmine'. I have tried installing it locally and globally, neither works. [This is what it looks like after installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaXXC.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm worried I unknowingly screwed something up.

Answer (score 0):

try installing it using 'npm install jasmine-node -g'

Comment: No luck. Anything else I might try?